# Canonical question about different versions of Angular

Tags: discussion, questions, canonical

Recently out of a specific need to know the breakdown, new features and changes within the Angular versions from 2 to 10 (current) to prepare for technical interviews, created a question in SO (https://stackoverflow.com/q/62757170/5675325).

After feedback from jonrsharpe, deleted the question and wrote here this question to know better how to proceed (and I thank him right away as I wasn't familiar with this procedure).

---

Before asking the question, I tried to get that information myself and couldn't do it without using various links (and not yet sure I have the best information - which, considering we're in Angular version 10 already, doesn't make much sense that gathering such info is such a hustle). Each link had either one or more of the following problems

- Doesn't speak about all versions from 2 to 10
- We have to trust the person writing didn't make any mistake (leaving relevant information out, adding wrong information)
- Didn't include breakdown, new features and changes
- Not easily found
- The focus wasn't to provide the information this question seeks

The links used were

- https://medium.com/@lifenshades/difference-among-angular-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-breakdown-new-features-and-changes-811fb5f8e6f0
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework)
- https://www.edureka.co/blog/interview-questions/top-angularjs-interview-questions-2016/
- https://update.angular.io/

Learned also from jonrsharpe that could use also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

---

Searching in SO could find similar questions lead me to find various similar questions that were only interested in knowing the differences from one version to another. As these were all active questions, more than one and with various upvotes and views, this allowed me to see that questions with differences between specific versions are seen as acceptable in the community. More precisely,

- [Differences Between Angular 5 and Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50720563/5675325)
- [Difference between angular 4 and 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52815570/5675325)
- [What is Angular 4 and from where I can learn more about it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41692462/5675325)
- [Major difference between Angular 1.2.x vs Angular 1.6.x version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44920310/5675325)

Even though there's already an existing question with a similar title ([Difference between angular versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797476/difference-between-angular-versions)), the question isn't really about understanding the version, new features and changes.

Comment: Personally, I don't like these kinds of questions. They are essentially list questions, with the list being a changelog, although since Angular 2 was a rewrite of the ideas of AngularJS into a new form, it's more than that even. And then someone else will ask the same question when Angular 11 comes out in six months or whatever, and we'll be in the same place. Seems like this would be a great blog post, or a GitHub repo, that could be kept up to date by people, rather than a Stack Overflow Q&A pair.

Comment: Taking just your first example of "questions acceptable to the community," notice that the highest upvoted answer is a laundry list of items with very little descriptive text, and a "more information" link at the bottom.  The accepted answer is merely an offsite link that apparently now redirects to a "What's New in Angular 9" page.  All in all, a rather disappointing outcome.

Comment: @HereticMonkey the question can be asked to give space for updating existing answers with new versions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey about that one, even the accepted answer wasn't able to provide a one link only answer

Comment: How many new version? There's a character limit for answers.... No, I would personally close such a question as too broad. If you want to know the detailed differences amongst that long of a history, do the research. If you want to share that research, there are innumerable ways of doing so outside of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why should this content be on Stack Overflow? Shouldn't the developers do this already via their release notes?

Comment: @HereticMonkey assuming versions will go on forever I can see that concern yes. Yet, up to this point we have up to version 10. Do you know if more and how many will come?

Comment: @Braiam fair point. They do have some of that information in their GitHub (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) but the focus is more on new features and bug fixes as opposed to new features and changes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe what is the final decision here? Ask it or not?