# Are changelog type questions acceptable?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

Are changelog type questions acceptable on SO?

By changelog, I mean questions like: 'what are the concrete API differences between version 1 of Foo and version 2?' or, the [specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67050798/1456253) regarding assembly versions that prompted this one.

I'm sure there is a meta about this, but after a number of minutes of searching, nothing has come up, so perhaps this dup will be useful for future people wondering the same thing.

In some situations it seems that this type of question would be too broad, for instance, asking for the difference between python 2.7 to python 3.1 or from java 8 to 11.

But as the size of the api grows smaller perhaps it becomes in scope? If there are literally only two changes between versions, surely that's within scope?

Perhaps you must go another level deeper? What are the changes made to a subgroup of code (like IO) between version 1 and 2?

Unlike other questions related to features, answers to these types of questions would be well defined since there are an enumerable number of changes and non-opinion based since the changes are objective. Furthermore, the answer does not change. Once version 1 and 2 of Foo is out, the diff is set.

Obviously one should be able to diff the documentation yourself, but if someone off-hand knows the changes and they are limited in number, that answer does seem like it would be helpful.

Comment: Related (albeit quite old) MSE threads - **1)** https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148097/is-there-a-canonical-response-to-back-up-the-statement-that-list-questions-are ; **2)** https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180335/are-there-good-list-questions-as-opposed-to-bad-list-questions

Comment: Questions should usually be about the "how" and not the "what". A question just asking for a changelog seems redundant as there are 100 % information to be found elsewhere. Such a question should rather ask *how* a change improves something or *how* to use a new feature, not *what* is new. You also run into "too broad"-territory very quickly.

Comment: Related example: [Canonical question about different versions of Angular](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399099/2821954)

Comment: i mean... while such a question may in some way fit within the guidelines/rules, i'd find it difficult to not downvote them.

Comment: @akuzminykh The specific question this refers to was about which instructions have been added between two revisions of a CPU architecture.  The vendor did not release a list of changes and digging out the handful of changes from 1000s of pages of manual is extremely cumbersome to do.

Comment: It's not off-topic by default, but most can be downvoted as they lack research effort. Reiterating a changelog on Stack Overflow is a waste of time and storage, or, if you're asking for changes between say 10 versions where looking at a changelog becomes difficult, it's likely too broad and closeworthy. There may be an exception for small projects that are documented extremely poorly (so poor that with [sufficient research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/7296893) the question stands), but in general, tread with caution.

Comment: @fuz A problem I often see on Meta is that people ask a general question while having a special case in mind. I just try to offer a general opinion that may not cover all special cases. It would be wonderful if this Meta-post would be written around the specific case.

Comment: @akuzminykh Seems like OP has just added a reference to the specific question.  Unfortunately, understanding that the difference is quite small and asking for it is reasonable requires some domain knowledge of assembly programming.  There, it is fairly standard to program against multiple architecture versions, keeping the differences in mind so the program can work with all of them/has conditional code for the differences.

Comment: @akuzminykh Great advice! I think following that will lead towards good questions. I agree that list questions are likely to elicit downvotes. But I'm trying to determine the rules here. What is closable vs not. Specifically, if a question asking for a changelog is not too broad, is it on topic? Or, is there something intrinsically too-broad about those type of questions.

Comment: @code11 You should think of SO-rules less like laws but more like guidelines. Think about how useful your post is for others. Trust in your and the community's common sense. What makes such question inherently more problematic is that they usually ask for something broad. That doesn't mean that such questions are useless per se. Write questions in a way that makes them focused on one thing so future users who are interested in exactly that thing can find it. E.g. when a version-bump brings 3 new features, then write 3 questions, not one. But at this point I'd prefer discussing a specific case.

Comment: @akuzminykh How can I write these three questions if I don't know which 3 new features there are?  This is the whole premise of the question this meta question is about: the vendor has not released sufficiently detailed release notes, so the question appeals to knowledgeable people to explain what changed.  Also, writing 1 new question per instruction that changed is neither sensible nor useful (since I specifically want that list of new instructions).  Also, in this specific case, the “how” is obvious.  Only the “what” is of interest.

Comment: Somewhat related: [*Question about entire library's compatibility not “too broad”?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342272/2751851)

Comment: @fuz But that's what I'm answering: If you guys think the question is appropriately scoped for the case and useful, then just post/keep it. The "3 questions"-example is just for illustration, to not respond in abstract blabla the whole time.

Comment: @akuzminykh This is the crux of the issue: I believe it is appropriately scoped, but the people who tried to close it didn't.  A long-ish debate ensued after which the question was reopened with some token changes.  This meta question was posted here to discuss the general case for future occurences of the same situation.

Comment: @fuz As one of the closers, I'll give my point of view: your question seemed to be about difference between two architectures which is way too broad and not programming specific. I might have read it wrong, or being too pedantic, but phrasing the question more specifically about the IS might have changed my view on the question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Well it is.  But it's not two unrelated architectures, but rather two versions of the same architecture with very small and subtle changes between them.  And these differences matter for programming and pretty much for programming only.  Nobody else but a low-level machine programmer really needs to know about these things.

Comment: @fuz Well, as someone writing Assembly for processors I design with Verilog I tend to consider architectural changes as more than just programming related and hence my confusion with your question. Hope you can get an answer!

Comment: @fuz "*I believe it is appropriately scoped, but the people who tried to close it didn't*" A couple things: the people who voted to close did so, there was no "try" here. Second, you asked two overlapping/redundant questions and a 3rd opinion-based question. Both of those issues were resolved in your edit, which resulted in the question being reopened. I'm not sure what issue you have with the process. And, for what it's worth, the changes were not "token", but fundamental to the actual question you posed.

Comment: @TylerH The kind of answer I expect for the updated question is very similar to the kind of answer i expected for the original.  So yes, a token change.

Comment: @fuz I personally think that these long-ish debates on Meta are often not as useful and constructive as one might think, especially not in the comment-section. Anyways, why don't you write an answer?

Comment: @akuzminykh To the meta question?  Maybe I should, yeah.

Comment: Could be duplicate, but mostly about one (and probably the only) question that passed the tests - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396173/are-we-playing-favorites-with-high-rep-users-self-answering-off-topic-questions - still with a lot of debate. TLDR: *self-answered* with a  *complete and verifiable* list of <40 items probably ok.

Comment: Mildly related, if a changelog is exceedingly hidden/ hard to find: [When is a resource request on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385479/when-is-a-resource-request-on-topic). My experience is that documentation for libraries and software is pretty accessible nowadays though, so I don't expect changelog fetch quest questions are very common.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, but there's a few caveats

**Supplement, don't copy**

If there's a real changelog, don't just run out and copy-paste a changelog into an answer and slap a "What changed?" in for a question. I don't think [this C++17 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38060437/2370483) is all that useful because it seems to do just that (there's some commentary woven in, but not enough that it doesn't look like an infodump). If someone else has compiled a list, you can use it as a starting point *but you must include some practical discussion and/or examples*. [We no longer have Stack Overflow Documentation for a reason.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation) We don't need to be a backup copy for every changelog made.

**Limited comparisons**

> Version X came out today. What changed?

That's far too broad of a scope. Compare it to a specific prior version so we're not comparing every change since Version 1.0. If the question is specific, (and there's no changelog to purely copy off of) a compiled list is the kind of thing Stack Overflow was made for.

**Targeted questions about specific changes are still preferred**

Ideally you don't need one rollup question, but a series of more targeted ones where you can flesh out changes. Some examples would be

- [C++17: explicit conversion function vs explicit constructor + implicit conversions - have the rules changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53101121/c17-explicit-conversion-function-vs-explicit-constructor-implicit-conversio)
- [What is <=> (the 'Spaceship' Operator) in PHP 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365346/what-is-the-spaceship-operator-in-php-7)
- [What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

All are about changes in versions, but they focus on one aspect, which makes them far more useful than an overall list.

**Make useful content**

To reiterate my first point, infodumps are unhelpful because we generally don't want a list. What you want to aim for is helping future users start using Version X (because they know Version W pretty well). If your question can do that, by all means ask it. But if it's just a re-tread (and moderators *will* delete pure copied content) or long on lists and short on useful info, expect it to get flagged and deleted.

Comment: Here's an example of what not to do, that I nevertheless do not regret doing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252212/ive-decided-not-to-support-ie7-what-js-css-html-features-can-i-now-use/10253362#10253362

Comment: the C++ question you linked has over a thousand upvotes, and the answer even more, so the information is quite sought after. I'm not sure what is the actual reason we don't want this? Surely, if 1000+ people found it useful, it's countering the "not that useful" viewpoint?

Comment: Partially agree but not completely. IMO even a bare list of changes (like the C++17 one, perhaps, though I'm not a C++ guy) is potentially a useful resource *if* it doesn't exist elsewhere. If it's copied and pasted directly from an official changelog, on the other hand, it clearly ain't useful.

Comment: @MarkAmery I think we have a lot of answers that are copied and pasted from some official manual (and we even have a bounty reason requesting an answer that is derived from official sources). If a copy and paste from changelog "clearly ain't useful", what's the difference in comparison to copy and paste from official docs? Are those bad too, even if they directly answer the question?

Comment: @eis A fair question. I think many answers that are solely a quote from the official docs *can* be useful simply by surfacing information that would be tricky to find in the docs, e.g. because it's nonobvious where to look or what to search for. The difference here is that there's a well-known convention of publishing "changelogs" or "release notes" with new versions of software, so most readers will know to look at such a document (if it exists) to see what's changed. If a Q&A pair simply duplicates an already easy-to-find changelog to Stack Overflow, it's likely not helping anyone.

Comment: @eis For specific questions, quoting manuals is sometimes sufficient (with proper citation). [Even I have done it on occasion.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27303248/2370483) What I'm cautioning against is taking, say, [a normal changelog](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-8.php#8.0.3) and just repasting the whole thing with minimal or no other content at all. Or, in the case of the C++17 question, making a basic question so you have an excuse to do so. And upvotes are not always an indicator of quality. In that case, it has enough other content it's not worth trying to close.

Comment: "Yes, but there's a few caveats" all the caveats basically boils down to don't do this.

Comment: Points in that C++17 answer's favor: it's CW and been edited by ~15 people over the years. Though, it wasn't originally CW, it *should* have been... might be something all such questions need.

Comment: @TylerH I feel that you can argue that it shouldn't have originally been CW. It's a lot of work to gather all that information, so I think it's very reasonable to argue that Yakk deserves to get the reputation for the answer, at least initially.

Answer (score 8):

No, there are better questions to be asked:

**Adapting/migrating old code to new method**

These usually focus on a very specific aspect that changed and those changes are breaking. Python `print()` is one example that comes to mind. Languages/frameworks/libraries usually try to avoid these and give plenty of time for migration and depreciation messages when they do. These are usually listed in a breaking changes section. "I'm updating my code to next standardsand I'm having trouble replacing <this removed feature>, how can I obtain the behavior of <removed featured>?" is another possible question.

**If the characteristic is a list, don't ask for what is new in version X, ask directly for the list**

This come to mind when the problem to solve is basically listing everything the target object is capable to do. For example, registers of a hardware device. You don't need to ask everytime there's a new version for the new addresses, you just need to ask for someone to list all potential addresses. Questions like "what members this object have", "what are the required parameters to pass to function x()", etc. Note here that this is not "what this library/language can do" list, but rather something very specific and contained. These sadly has to be reigned in with extreme care, so they don't go scope creep like ["what are all the possible causes of a NullPointerException"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/792066).

**But more importantly, ask for X, not for Y**

Many times people ask about the problem with the solution, not about the problem itself. If there's a problem with the new version, ask about *that*. Chances are that the same problem existed before, just that now it has a new solution with at least one answer edited [to include the new thing.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/493399/792066) Those cover all your bases.

**Then, where do the changelogs live at?**

Many opensource projects have wiki's, they could be there. In the case of closed source, there usually are some forums, mailing list, etc. where it can be posted. Failing all that, there's your personal blog.